# Using algolia (php website) - Looking for the best update/delete method?

Tags: php, algolia

I have looked into how I could specify objectID when initially indexing objects, but this doesn't seem possible. As the system has no knowledge of Algolia auto-generated objectID's - what is the best way to deal with update/delete actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to specify your [ObjectID](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/formatting-your-data/#unique-identifier---objectid).

Quoting from the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/formatting-your-data/#unique-identifier---objectid):

> Every object is uniquely identified by an objectID. If you don’t provide one, Algolia will generate one automatically. However, it will be easier to remove or update records if you have stored a unique identifier in the objectID attribute.

Comment: Thanks Guy. I was using the Algolia API clients, and read through the source shortly after asking the question here. Within the addObjects method, you can specify object ID key.